# Can we replace nuget.config file with command parameters?

Tags: nuget, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am working on an Azure pipeline to run on a Windows self-hosted agent.
We configured a Artefact feed with an upstream to connect to Nuget.
As we are behind a firewall, it seems the only way to connect to Nuget.

My pipeline was working with this nuget.config file :

```
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="FeedName" value="https://***.pkgs.visualstudio.com/***/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
```

And this YAML:

```
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: '"C:\dotnet\dotnet.exe" publish ${{ parameters.solutionToPublishPath }} -c ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }} -o $(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
```

The nuget.config file breaks the previous pipelines in TeamCity!!
To keep the old one running while I work on the new one, I am looking for a way to move the information from the nuget.config file to the script.

Is it possible ?

I tried with this:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: '"C:\dotnet\dotnet.exe" add "src/project/project.API.csproj" package FeedName -s https://***.pkgs.visualstudio.com/***/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v3/index.json'
```

I get this message which for me indicates that it tried to reach Nuget directly and failed, this is why we use a feed.

```
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 302 (Moved Temporarily).
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you elaborate "The nuget.config file breaks the previous pipelines in TeamCity"? Do you mean the nuget.config setting affect other build?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't the one working in TeamCity but it seems that as the FeedName in the nuget file goes to the Azure feed, it is not allowed to reach the URL, they never succeed to make TeamCity update the nuget packages because security is very restrictive here, at that time, they decided to copy locally the nuget packages.   Renaming the file to "___nuget.config" fixed TeamCity and broke Azure, I'll have to work on a different branch until we move out of TeamCity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not call it a solution as I can't move the nuget.config information out of the file into the command line, I'll remove the file to enable Team City to work and put it back when running Azure pipelines. Thanks.

Comment: You could add this `<disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="FeedName" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>` in your nuget.config to disable this feed or you could just remove it from your repo.

Answer (score 0):

You may check [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) extension to see whether it helps you. It can replace tokens in files with variable values during pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

We are overriding Nuget.config in Azure DevOps pipeline script with *DotNetCoreCLI@2* and *restoreArguments*

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: |
     $(buildProjects)
     !$(testProjects)
    restoreArguments: --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json --source $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Nugets
```